# error doing nested resource in grails

Tags: json, angularjs, grails-2.0

i am try to do nested resource call using angular and grails.

in my account domain i map domain this way:

example:

```
class Account {
        static hasMany=[contacts:Contacts,users:User_BE];
   }
```

and in contact domain
example:

```
class Contacts {
    static belongsTo=[accounts:Account];
}
```

my json structure is like this:

```
 {"accountType":"Single","traderwinkel":true,"lynxAgro":true,"contacts":[{"class":"com.crm.contacts","name":"abc"}]}
```

i am getting this error:

```
null id in com.crm.Contacts entry
```

and i am also try to send json without using array like this:

```
{"accountType":"Single","traderwinkel":true,"lynxAgro":true,"contacts":{"class":"com.crm.contacts","name":"abc"}}

but got same error like above.
```

and also i have used restfullcontroller:

```
class AccountController extends RestfulController { 
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
}
```

please suggest me how should i need to structure and send json data

Comment: Is your Contacts object persisted to the database already?